# mysql SELECT from 3 tables where 2 of them could be null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I'd like to ask you for help with a query (mysql). I have 3 tables:

1.table "reviews"

```
ID     | content                     |
--------------------------------------
1      | content of first review
2      | content of second review
```

2.table "pros"

```
ID     |  reviews_ID  |  pros         |
---------------------------------------
1      |          1   |  good service |
2      |          1   |  nice look    |
3      |          1   |  not bad price|
4      |          2   |  good service |
5      |          2   |  design       |
```

3.table "cons"

```
ID     |  reviews_ID  |  pros         |
---------------------------------------
1      |          1   |  delays       |
4      |          2   |  mistakes     |
5      |          2   |  troubles     |
```

What I am trying to do is merge informations from these 3 tables, where "reviews" table is the main one and table 2, 3 are pointing to it (reviews_ID).

I'd like to get results like this:

```
=> content of first review
   + good service       - delays
   + nice look
   + not bad price
```

of course in array/result, this is just for better understand :)

Comment: You like to get those results but you haven't tried anything?

Comment: Dear @ChristianMark, If you would know me, You know, that I'm kind of person who is trying to solve everything by myself and as a last chance, I am asking for help. It was 3:30AM here and I had tried maybe 50 other queries from 8:00pm before I asked. I really didn't have power for explaining, what I tried and I was pretty much close to final results -> in fact, I could saw all of requested results in SQL, but there were duplicates. As far as I understand, you are helping to keep high level of this server, right? With all my understand for your job, I have to say, your comment helped to nobody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8dfe48/17/0)
with `GROUP_CONCAT` you can explode pros and cons into an array or whatever in php.

```
SELECT content,p.pros,c.cons
FROM reviews
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT reviews_id,GROUP_CONCAT(pros)as pros
   FROM pros
   GROUP BY reviews_id)as p
 ON p.reviews_id = reviews.id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT reviews_id,GROUP_CONCAT(cons)as cons
   FROM cons
   GROUP BY reviews_id)as c
 ON c.reviews_id = reviews.id
WHERE reviews.id = 1;
```

result will be

```
CONTENT                     PROS                                    CONS
content of first review     good service,nice look,not bad service  delays
```

Comment: thank you for editing my answer! and OP should be aware of there is size LIMIT of GROUP_CONCAT()'s output value. refer to http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/120438-solved-group-concat-max-length/

Comment: i didn't know about the size limit thanks for mentioning that

Comment: Dear @TinTran. Thank you very much. I even didn't know about "GROUP_CONCAT". I am still learning, however I tried maybe 50other queries before I asked :)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT statement produces only two-dimensional table. so, you could not obtain hierarchical  tree using STANDARD SELECT. I suggest following SQL and convert display format in client side.

```
SELECT 'content',r.content as value
FROM reviews r
WHERE r.ID = 1

UNION

SELECT 'pros', p.pros
FROM reviews r LEFT JOIN pros p
  ON r.ID = p.reviews_ID
WHERE r.ID = 1

UNION

SELECT 'cons', c.cons
FROM reviews r LEFT JOIN cons c
  ON r.ID = c.reviews_ID
WHERE r.ID = 1
```

Comment: Even I accepted previous answer, your example with UNIONS is much more understandable for me and maybe I will use it :D Thank you @Jungsu Heo

Comment: @FredericoRossini you're very welcome! as I mentioned Tin's answer. there is size LIMIT. be careful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.content, B.pros, C.cons
FROM reviews A LEFT JOIN pros B ON A.ID = B.reviews_ID
  LEFT JOIN cons C ON A.ID = C.reviews_ID
```